# how use NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults in cocos2d?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have items. All is open except 10. to open level 10 should be completed any 5? It is my screenshot http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_9304644_10796687.png.

And how to use NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults for save completed levels? 
I'm just beginner and i can not understand some things. I will be grateful if you could help me and I will try to explain in detail.

Thanks

```
    CCMenu *menuLevel_1 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuLevel_1_Item, nil];
    menuLevel_1.position = ccp(size.width/9,size.height/1.4);
    [self addChild:menuLevel_1 z:3];

    CCLabelTTF *label_1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] fontName:@"Avenir" fontSize:35];
    label_1.position = ccp(menuLevel_1_Item.contentSize.width/2, menuLevel_1_Item.contentSize.height/2);
    [menuLevel_1_Item addChild:label_1];

   CCMenuItemSprite *menuLevel_2_Item = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"button_level"] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"button_level_clicked"] target:self selector:@selector(Level_2_Scene:)];


    CCMenu *menuLevel_2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuLevel_2_Item, nil];
    menuLevel_2.position = ccp(size.width/4,size.height/1.4);
    [self addChild:menuLevel_2 z:3];

    CCLabelTTF *label_2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"] fontName:@"Avenir" fontSize:35];
    label_2.position = ccp(menuLevel_2_Item.contentSize.width/2, menuLevel_2_Item.contentSize.height/2);
    [menuLevel_2_Item addChild:label_2];

.........

 CCMenuItemSprite *menuLevel_10_Item = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"button_level_lock"] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"button_level_clicked"] target:self selector:@selector(Level_10_Scene:)];


    CCMenu *menuLevel_10 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuLevel_10_Item, nil];
    menuLevel_10.position = ccp(size.width/1.5,size.height/1.8);
    [self addChild:menuLevel_10 z:3];
```

Comment: don't repeatedly ask the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656719/how-create-levels-with-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use NSUserDefaults for that , create a custom GameState class and if the contents are not too big using NSCoding should do the work.

Here's an example of a GameState Class.

First you'll need a Class to handle storing

**Database Class Header**

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
       id loadData(NSString * filename);
       void saveData(id theData, NSString *filename);
```

**Database Class Implementation**

```
#import "GCDatabase.h"
        NSString * pathForFile(NSString *filename) {
            // 1
            NSArray *paths =
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                NSUserDomainMask,
                                                YES);
// 2
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            // 3
            return [documentsDirectory
                stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
        id loadData(NSString * filename) {
            // 4
            NSString *filePath = pathForFile(filename);
            // 5
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
// 6
        NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc]
            initWithContentsOfFile:filePath] autorelease];
// 7
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]
            initForReadingWithData:data] autorelease];
// 8
        id retval = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Data"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
        return retval;
}
return nil; }
void saveData(id theData, NSString *filename) {
    // 9
    NSMutableData *data = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];
    // 10
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]
        initForWritingWithMutableData:data] autorelease];
    // 11
    [archiver encodeObject:theData forKey:@"Data"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    // 12
    [data writeToFile:pathForFile(filename) atomically:YES];
```

**Game State Header**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface GameState : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    BOOL completedLevel1;
    BOOL completedLevel2;
    BOOL completedLevel3;
    BOOL completedLevel4;
    BOOL completedLevel5;
    int timesFell;
}
+ (GameState *) sharedInstance;
- (void)save;
@property (assign) BOOL completedLevel1;
@property (assign) BOOL completedLevel2;
@property (assign) BOOL completedLevel3;
@property (assign) BOOL completedLevel4;
@property (assign) BOOL completedLevel5;
@property (assign) int timesFell;
@end
```

**Game State Implementation**

```
    #import "GameState.h"
       #import "GCDatabase.h"
       @implementation GameState
       @synthesize completedLevel1;
       @synthesize completedLevel2;
       @synthesize completedLevel3;
       @synthesize completedLevel4;
       @synthesize completedLevel5;
       @synthesize timesFell;
       static GameState *sharedInstance = nil;
       +(GameState*)sharedInstance {
            @synchronized([GameState class])
            {
                if(!sharedInstance) {
                     sharedInstance = [loadData(@"GameState") retain];
                      if (!sharedInstance) {
                          [[self alloc] init];
                      }
                  }
                return sharedInstance;
}
return nil; }
+(id)alloc {
            @synchronized ([GameState class])
            {
                NSAssert(sharedInstance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a \
                        second instance of the GameState singleton");
                sharedInstance = [super alloc];
                return sharedInstance;
            }
return nil; }
        - (void)save {
            saveData(self, @"GameState");
        }
        - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
            [encoder encodeBool:completedLevel1 forKey:@"CompletedLevel1"];

[encoder encodeBool:completedLevel2 forKey:@"CompletedLevel2"];
    [encoder encodeBool:completedLevel3 forKey:@"CompletedLevel3"];
    [encoder encodeBool:completedLevel4 forKey:@"CompletedLevel4"];
    [encoder encodeBool:completedLevel5 forKey:@"CompletedLevel5"];
    [encoder encodeInt:timesFell forKey:@"TimesFell"];
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        completedLevel1 = [decoder
            decodeBoolForKey:@"CompletedLevel1"];
        completedLevel2 = [decoder
            decodeBoolForKey:@"CompletedLevel2"];
        completedLevel3 = [decoder
            decodeBoolForKey:@"CompletedLevel3"];
        completedLevel4 = [decoder
            decodeBoolForKey:@"CompletedLevel4"];
        completedLevel5 = [decoder
            decodeBoolForKey:@"CompletedLevel5"];
        timesFell = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"TimesFell"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: it from the book The IOS Game Programming Collection ))). How to make this easier ?

Comment: Easier? Well persistent storage in mobile devices are mostly complicated, the step to take to be able to make it "easier" would be to use core data. It's easy once you get to know the whole core data structure, but might be hard at the beggining.